# jQuery not working universal app

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, win-universal-app

**Thanks for your help, I have found the answer:
I needed to add this to the manifest: ms-appx-web:///default.html**

I am working on a universal app (more a web app).
But I can't seem to get jQuery working.
I downloaded jQuery with nuget.
Here's my default.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App4</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="WinJS/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="WinJS/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="WinJS/js/ui.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <!-- App4 references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="Message">
        This is a Welcome Message
    </div>
    <button id="btnDisplay">
        Click Me
    </button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#btnDisplay").click(function () {
                $("#Message").hide();
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm stuck...Anyone knows what I am doing wrong/need to do?

Comment: `"medium"` is not a valid value for `fadeToggle()`'s `duration` argument. That might explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> fadeToggle Description: Display or hide the matched elements by
>   animating their opacity.

it should be:

```
 <style type="text/css">
        #Message {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    </style>
```

and you are not using correct parameter for fadeToggle

> .fadeToggle( [duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )

see [here](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)

Comment: Thanks! But it still does not work, I changed it now to this (see my updated answer), just to test jQuery

Comment: Yes, CSS is gone so it's visible now so when I click the button it should hide

Comment: test  $(document).ready(function ()  writing some alert("alert") inside, check if this function is executed

Comment: do that also inside  $("#btnDisplay").click(function () {